# Free profinite products

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $F$ be a nonabelian finitely generated free profinite group, and let $x \in F$. Must there be some $1 \neq y \in F$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is isomorphic to the free profinite product of $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$ ?

Comment: It seems plausible that this can be proved using the theory of profinite trees.  You should check the papers of Zalesskii and his co-authors.